# Adding custom html inside Mapbox GL JS Popup on click event

Tags: vue.js, mapbox-gl-js, quasar-framework, mapbox-gl

I am creating a pop up using official docs per https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup/

But inside the html I would like to set custom Quasar Vue components, such as images, buttons, .etc

I am wondering if that is even possible and if so what would be the syntax for it.
Below is an example of what I would like to achieve with **popup.setHTML()**.

The simple p tag will render correctly but the button wont work using q-btn quasar directive.

```
  map.on('click', layerID, (e) => {

  const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: [0, -15]})
            .setLngLat(LngLat)
            .setHTML(
              `<div>
                <p>Some Text</p>
                <q-btn  @click="alert('hello world')" >Button Title</q-btn>
               </div>`
            );

  popup.addTo(map);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this we first need to create a VNode (virtual node) using the [`h()` function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html)

Then at the [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) we render this VNode inside the newly created Popup by utilising the `render()` function, where we point it towards a specific DOM element with id inside the popup:

```
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import { h, nextTick, render } from "vue";
import type { GeoJSON, Point } from "geojson";
import MapPopupComponent from "./components/MapPopupComponent.vue";

// (...) Code instantiating the map, geoJson source and layers rendering the GeoJson source

map.on("click", "geoJsonMarkers", (e) => {
  const feature = e.features?.at(0);
  const coordinates = (
    feature?.geometry as Point | undefined
  )?.coordinates.slice() as[number, number] | undefined;

  console.debug("Clicked", feature);

  if (!coordinates) {
    return;
  }

  new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML('<div id="map-popup-content">Hello</div>')
    .addTo(map);

  nextTick(() => {
    const popupComp = h(MapPopupComponent, {
      // Add props, eventListeners etc. here
      ad: feature?.properties,
      onClick: (e) => {console.debug("An event with name 'click' was fired from popup component")}
    });

    // Tell Vue to render the VNode inside the element with id
    render(popupComp, document.getElementById("map-popup-content")!);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Mathias! Thank you! I appreciate your effort, upvoting for now and will accept once tested! Project is currently on pause, but I will get back to you on this once I get to test this solution.

Comment: @Mishka thank you for the reply even though it is paused. I was looking around for the same question and ended up with this solution :) Hope it will be of use sometime